# is there a way to make the status bar text to bold in iOS?

Tags: ios

I'm searching to make my status bar text (time, carrier) to Bold but not getting anything, is there any way to bold status bar text?

Answer (score 0):

No. It's not possible. iOS apps run in a sandbox environment so this is not possible in a non-jailbroken device.